# Class Not Found Exception in KMeanClustering--Mahout

Tags: hadoop, cluster-analysis, classnotfoundexception, mahout, k-means

Hi i'm trying to run [SimpleKmeanClustering](https://github.com/tdunning/MiA/blob/master/src/main/java/mia/clustering/ch07/SimpleKMeansClustering.java) Code, from Github to see how clustering works,
I'm able to complile the code on my windows Eclipse.

I made a jar of my project, i want to run it on a single node Hadoop cluster(**CHD-4.2.1**), with mahout installed on it. The mahout examples run fine on this cluster, so no issues regarding installation.

I use the following command in command Promt to run my jar, i'm not sure if i'm trying in right way.

> user@INFPH01463U:~$ mahout jar /home/user/apurv/Kmean.jar
>   tryout.SimpleKMeansClustering

I got corresponding error

> MAHOUT_LOCAL is not set; adding HADOOP_CONF_DIR to classpath. Running
>   on hadoop, using /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop and
>   HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf MAHOUT-JOB:
>   /usr/lib/mahout/mahout-examples-0.7-cdh4.3.0-job.jar 13/06/06 14:42:18
>   WARN driver.MahoutDriver: Unable to add class: jar
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jar
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
>           at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.addClass(MahoutDriver.java:236)
>           at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:128)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208) 13/06/06 14:42:18 WARN driver.MahoutDriver: No jar.props found on
>   classpath, will use command-line arguments only Unknown program 'jar'
>   chosen. Valid program names are:   arff.vector: : Generate Vectors
>   from an ARFF file or directory   baumwelch: : Baum-Welch algorithm for
>   unsupervised HMM training   canopy: : Canopy clustering   cat: : Print
>   a file or resource as the logistic regression models would see it
>   cleansvd: : Cleanup and verification of SVD output   clusterdump: :
>   Dump cluster output to text   clusterpp: : Groups Clustering Output In
>   Clusters   cmdump: : Dump confusion matrix in HTML or text formats
>   cvb: : LDA via Collapsed Variation Bayes (0th deriv. approx)
>   cvb0_local: : LDA via Collapsed Variation Bayes, in memory locally.
>   dirichlet: : Dirichlet Clustering   eigencuts: : Eigencuts spectral
>   clustering   evaluateFactorization: : compute RMSE and MAE of a rating
>   matrix factorization against probes   fkmeans: : Fuzzy K-means
>   clustering   fpg: : Frequent Pattern Growth   hmmpredict: : Generate
>   random sequence of observations by given HMM   itemsimilarity: :
>   Compute the item-item-similarities for item-based collaborative
>   filtering   kmeans: : K-means clustering   lucene.vector: : Generate
>   Vectors from a Lucene index   matrixdump: : Dump matrix in CSV format 
>   matrixmult: : Take the product of two matrices   meanshift: : Mean
>   Shift clustering   minhash: : Run Minhash clustering   parallelALS: :
>   ALS-WR factorization of a rating matrix   recommendfactorized: :
>   Compute recommendations using the factorization of a rating matrix
>   recommenditembased: : Compute recommendations using item-based
>   collaborative filtering   regexconverter: : Convert text files on a
>   per line basis based on regular expressions   rowid: : Map
>   SequenceFile to
>   {SequenceFile,
>   SequenceFile}   rowsimilarity: : Compute the
>   pairwise similarities of the rows of a matrix   runAdaptiveLogistic: :
>   Score new production data using a probably trained and validated
>   AdaptivelogisticRegression model   runlogistic: : Run a logistic
>   regression model against CSV data   seq2encoded: : Encoded Sparse
>   Vector generation from Text sequence files   seq2sparse: : Sparse
>   Vector generation from Text sequence files   seqdirectory: : Generate
>   sequence files (of Text) from a directory   seqdumper: : Generic
>   Sequence File dumper   seqmailarchives: : Creates SequenceFile from a
>   directory containing gzipped mail archives   seqwiki: : Wikipedia xml
>   dump to sequence file   spectralkmeans: : Spectral k-means clustering 
>   split: : Split Input data into test and train sets   splitDataset: :
>   split a rating dataset into training and probe parts   ssvd: :
>   Stochastic SVD   svd: : Lanczos Singular Value Decomposition   testnb:
>   : Test the Vector-based Bayes classifier   trainAdaptiveLogistic: :
>   Train an AdaptivelogisticRegression model   trainlogistic: : Train a
>   logistic regression using stochastic gradient descent   trainnb: :
>   Train the Vector-based Bayes classifier   transpose: : Take the
>   transpose of a matrix   validateAdaptiveLogistic: : Validate an
>   AdaptivelogisticRegression model against hold-out data set   vecdist:
>   : Compute the distances between a set of Vectors (or Cluster or
>   Canopy, they must fit in memory) and a list of Vectors   vectordump: :
>   Dump vectors from a sequence file to text   viterbi: : Viterbi
>   decoding of hidden states from given output states sequence 13/06/06
>   14:42:18 INFO driver.MahoutDriver: Program took 2 ms (Minutes:
>   3.3333333333333335E-5)

Here is my code which i'm using:

Code

```
package tryout;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.mahout.math.RandomAccessSparseVector;
import org.apache.mahout.math.Vector;
import org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable;
import org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.Kluster;
import org.apache.mahout.clustering.classify.WeightedVectorWritable;
import org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver;
import org.apache.mahout.common.distance.EuclideanDistanceMeasure;

public class SimpleKMeansClustering {
    public static final double[][] points = { {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}, 
                                              {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {8, 8},
                                              {9, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 9}};    


    public static void writePointsToFile(List<Vector> points,
            String fileName,FileSystem fs,Configuration conf) throws IOException {    
        Path path = new Path(fileName);    
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        SequenceFile.Writer writer = new SequenceFile.Writer(fs, conf,path, LongWritable.class, VectorWritable.class);    

        long recNum = 0;    
        VectorWritable vec = new VectorWritable();    
        for (Vector point : points) {       
         vec.set(point);      
          writer.append(new LongWritable(recNum++), vec);    
        }    writer.close();  
    }    

    public static List<Vector> getPoints(double[][] raw) {    
        List<Vector> points = new ArrayList<Vector>();    
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {      
            double[] fr = raw[i];      
            Vector vec = new RandomAccessSparseVector(fr.length);      
            vec.assign(fr);      
            points.add(vec);    
        }    
        return points;  
    }    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {        
        int k = 2;        
        List<Vector> vectors = getPoints(points);        
        File testData = new File("testdata");    
        if (!testData.exists()) {      
            testData.mkdir();    
        }    
        testData = new File("testdata/points");    
        if (!testData.exists()) {      
            testData.mkdir();    
        }        
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();    
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);    
        writePointsToFile(vectors, "testdata/points/file1", fs, conf);        
        Path path = new Path("testdata/clusters/part-00000");    
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        SequenceFile.Writer writer = new SequenceFile.Writer(fs, conf,path, Text.class, Kluster.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {      
            Vector vec = vectors.get(i);      
            Kluster cluster = new Kluster(vec, i, new EuclideanDistanceMeasure());      
            writer.append(new Text(cluster.getIdentifier()), cluster);    
        }    
        writer.close();        

        KMeansDriver.run(conf, new Path("testdata/points"), new Path("testdata/clusters"),      
                new Path("output"), new EuclideanDistanceMeasure(), 0.001, 10,
                true,0.0, false);        
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(fs,new Path("output/" + Kluster.CLUSTERED_POINTS_DIR+ "/part-m-00000"), conf);        
        IntWritable key = new IntWritable();   
        WeightedVectorWritable value = new WeightedVectorWritable();    
        while (reader.next(key, value)) {      
            System.out.println(value.toString() + " belongs to cluster " + key.toString());    
        }    
        reader.close();  
    }
}
```

Can anyone Guide me for this...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the command should read `mahout kmeans`, not `mahout jar`.

https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/k-means-clustering.html

Your command is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Your command doesn't run kmeans at all. You need to run something like this:

```
./bin/mahout kmeans -i reuters-vectors/tfidf-vectors/ -o mahout-clusters -c mahout-initial-centers -c 0.1 -k 20 -x 10 -ow
```

Refer the following link: https://mahout.apache.org/users/clustering/k-means-clustering.html